# how to handle error: -wmaybe-uninitialized

Tags: c, error-handling, makefile

i found this code and wanted to run it to learn from it, but on my pc (linux system) i get this error:

```
$ c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O2 ls.c
ls.c: In Funktion »list_dir«:
ls.c:44:9: Warnung: »pwd« could be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
   
44 | printf("%s \t %ld \t %s \t %s", pwd->pw_name, (long)my_stat.st_size, timebuf, cur_directory->d_name);
   |
```

how can i get rid of it by editing this code to work. On my friends PC it worked but not on mine. Is it because of the System or should i change something on the code. Thanks in advance

```
#includes ...
int list_dir(const char *dir)     { 

struct dirent* cur_directory;
struct stat my_stat;
struct tm lt;  
struct passwd *pwd; // User-ID

DIR* directory = opendir(dir);

    if(directory == NULL)     { 
    printf("list_dir : %s : %s \n", dir, strerror(errno));
    return 0;
}   

    printf("Directory : %s\n", dir);
    printf("\n");
    while( (cur_directory = readdir(directory) ) )     { 
    stat(cur_directory->d_name, &my_stat);  
        if ( (stat(cur_directory->d_name, &my_stat) ) == 0 )    {
        pwd = getpwuid(my_stat.st_uid); // Get User-ID
    }
        // Last Modified 
        time_t t = my_stat.st_mtime;
        localtime_r(&t, &lt);
        char timebuf[80];
        strftime(timebuf, sizeof(timebuf), "%c", &lt);
        if (pwd != 0) {
        printf("%s \t %ld \t %s \t %s", pwd->pw_name, (long)my_stat.st_size, timebuf, cur_directory->d_name);
        printf("\n");
        } 
        else {
        printf("%d \t %ld \t %s \t %s", my_stat.st_uid, (long)my_stat.st_size, timebuf, cur_directory->d_name);
        printf("\n");
    } 
}
    closedir(directory);        
    return 0; 
    }

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    if ( argc == 1 ) {
    return list_dir ( "." );
    } 
    else {
    int ret = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i += 1 ) {
    if ( list_dir ( argv[i] ) != 0 ) {
    ret = 1; 
    }
   }
   return ret;
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`pwd` is initialized inside `if`. If the condition is false, it is never initialized, so will be used uninitialized.

Initialize it in definition (good idea, avoids having the uninitialized state ever), or add `else` branch to initialize it in that case.

---

To initialize at definition:

```
struct passwd *pwd = NULL; // User-ID
```

To assign in `else`:

```
if ( (stat(cur_directory->d_name, &my_stat) ) == 0 ) {
    pwd = getpwuid(my_stat.st_uid); // Get User-ID
} else {
    pwd = NULL;
}
```

---

And, since that if is inside a loop, looks like ***you need the latter approach.***

Comment: and how would that look?

Comment: @user17978223 you are actually asking how you assign a value to a variable?

Comment: yes because my pc keeps on giving the same errors, im assuming there might be somethin wrong ab my system

Comment: and im new to programming in general

Comment: @user17978223 Added sample code. You might want to learn C, at least basics, before tackling as complex code as this.

Comment: @user17978223 Also, your indentation is very misleading. Please use auto-indenting / auto-format!